# Is this function Measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$. Let $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ denote the signal function of $f$. Is $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ a measurable function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** This functions can take only two values, so it's enough to see that $\{f=0\}$ and $\{f>0\}$ are measurable. These sets are actually respectively closed and open.

(the results holds if $f$ is supposed measurable, not necessarily continuous; in the argument just replace "closed" and "open" by "measurable")